# "docker-compose build" returning "exec format error"

Tags: debian, docker

When running the "docker-compose build" command, I'm running the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'seafile' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get 
update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ca-
certificates python2.7 python-setuptools python-imaging python-ldap 
python-urllib3 sqlite3 wget' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    #image: hypriot/rpi-mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mdh2019
    volumes:
    - /mnt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  duply:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /mnt/data:/mnt/data
      - ./webinterface:/var/www/html/MyDigitalHome
      - /mnt/guestbackup:/mnt/guestbackup/backup
      #- /mnt/usb-removable:/usb-removable
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "24:22"
    links:
      - db

  seafile:
    build: seafile/
    volumes:
      - ./seafile/config:/config
      - /mnt/data/seafile:/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN=default@xxxxxx.xy
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN_PW=xxxxxxxx

  owncloud:
    build: owncloud/
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/owncloud:/data
      - ./owncloud/config:/var/www/html/config
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    links:
      - db:mysql

  mailserver:
    build: mailserver/
    volumes:
      - "./mailserver/dovecot/10-mail.conf:/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:ro"
      - "./mailserver/fetchmail/fetchmailrc:/etc/fetchmailrc:ro"
      - "./mailserver/ssl/exim.crt:/etc/ssl/exim.crt:ro"
      - "./mailserver/ssl/exim.pem:/etc/ssl/exim.pem:ro"
      - "/mnt/data/mailserver:/var/mail"
      - "/mnt/data/mailserver/home:/home"
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "143:143"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
      - "8079:80"
      - "8078:443"
    links:
      - db
```

My dockerfile looks like:

```
# FROM debian
FROM armv7/armhf-debian

MAINTAINER Me

# install packages
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
ca-certificates \
python2.7 \
python-setuptools \
python-imaging \
python-ldap \
python-urllib3 \
sqlite3 \
wget

# Copy scripts
ADD ./scripts /scripts

# set environment variables
ENV SERVER_NAME mdh-seafile
ENV SERVER_IP 127.0.0.1
ENV FILESERVER_PORT 8082
ENV SEAFILE_DIR /data
ENV SEAFILE_VERSION seafile-server-6.0.8
ENV INSTALLPATH /opt/seafile/${SEAFILE_VERSION}/

# clean for smaller image
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Volumes for persistent configuration
VOLUME /opt/seafile/

# set entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT bash /scripts/init.sh
```

I'm using docker/Debian 9.

Comment: Are you sure the Dockerfile you've posted is the one you're trying to build? None of the packages in apt-get install command in the error are in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Kinda. maybe it's calling other files to install stuff?

Comment: Can you try building the image by itself without docker-compose? i.e using `docker build`

Comment: Dockerfile above works for me with `docker build`

Comment: I added the docker-compose.

Comment: What's the path of your Dockerfile?

Comment: @JShorthouse It's on Desktop/MDH/Dockerfile

Comment: Works for me with `docker-compose build`. What is your docker version (using 18.0 here).

Comment: @xenoid mine is 18.09.4

Comment: @Orange And that's for the `duply` service? If you look at your error it's the `seafile` service that failed to build, so the Dockerfile at `Desktop/MDH/seafile/Dockerfile` is the one that's has the problem.

Comment: @JShorthouse Okay, I changed it in my question.

Comment: @Orange Have you tried debugging interactively? You can run the container with `docker run -it armv7/armhf-debian bash`, which would get you in to the container's shell. Then, run the `apt-get` command and see what's going wrong. That should at least get you a more informative error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it:

Needed to change

```
# FROM debian
FROM armv7/armhf-debian
```

to:

```
FROM debian
# FROM armv7/armhf-debian
```

And comment everything in front of `# install packages`. That was the raspberry part in the Dockerfiles.

Thanks, everyone.